# Cannot find symbol Time in Java

Tags: java, time, compiler-errors, java.util.date

I am a newbie in Java and writing a very simple program. It looks perfect to me. 
I know that java.util.Date contains a Time object that can be used. 
This [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)) also provides some documentation on the same.
However when I run the program I get an error. Please help me figure out what's wrong here.

```
package timestuff;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TimeZone;


public class MyDays {

    private  Time start;
    private  double temp;

    public MyDays(final Time StartTime, final double Temperature) {
            start = StartTime;
            temp = Temperature;
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 MyDays.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        private  Time start;
                 ^
 symbol:   class Time
 location: class MyDays
```

Comment: " I know that java.util.Date contains a Time object that can be used." <-- where did you see that? The javadoc disagrees with you

Comment: The docs shared show --> 
java.lang.Object
  extended by java.util.Date
      extended by java.sql.Time

Comment: So I thought importing java.util.Date should automatically import java.sql.Time

Comment: No it won't. You need to import java.sql.Time explicitly as the answer says. Also, Date does not "contain" Time; it is `Time` which extends `Date`.

Comment: By your logic, importing [`java.lang.Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) would import **everything**. It obviously doesn't, so your logic must be wrong. No?

Comment: You are right. My logic was wrong here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import [time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html) class .

```
import java.sql.Time
```

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc doesn't say anything about a time class in java.util.Date

You import it.

```
import java.sql.Time
```